# Using RC Low Pass Filter for PWM signal Smoothing

Tags: pwm, low-pass, smoothing-capacitor

I have some questions regarding the working of RC Low pass filters, specifically for smoothing out high frequency PWM signals (application: making a buck converter for driving an LED (expected current approx 3Amps max on output side, input voltage 82DC, output 36DC):

- Is the only purpose of the resistor in the RC filter to limit the amount of current that flows into the capacitor, thereby making sure that it doesnt surpass a certain maximum SOC value? If theoretically a big enough capacitance value and a high enough PWM frequency for the input signal were to be chosen (such that the max. SOC the capacitor would reach under these conditions would be the same as with a smaller capacitance and lower frequency..) could the resistor in the RC filter be omitted since in this theoretical case the capacitor won't reach a higher SOC than in the case where there is a resistor present? Or does the resistor serve a different/additional purpose in the filter other than the one outlined above?
  Is another reason for adding the resistor because otherwise, in most cases, you'd need to have very big (and perhaps expensive) capacitors in your circuit to achieve the same filtering results? so therefore it makes sense to accept some heat losses through the resistor in exchange for being able to use a much smaller capacitor?
  PS: I have heard that the impedence of some components used in circuits can differ based on for example the frequency and therefore it cannot be considered a constant and that is a reason for adding a bigger fixed resistance into the filter in order to accurately control the cutoff point of the filter. Is this true?
- Can the resistor in the RC filter be replaced with an inductor if the inductance value is similar in order to reduce the heat-losses?
- do you need to initially charge the capacitor to a relatively high voltage (close to desired output voltage of in this case 36volt) before switching on the high frequency PWM signal? Since if you turn on the high frequency PWM signal when the capacitor is fully discharged, and if the frequency is high enough the capacitor won't have time to fully charge (to the desired output voltage or close to it) during one 'block' of the PWM blockform hence the voltage being output by the filter (during the time when the capacitor is discharging and hence the average voltage) will be lower??
  Or does it not matter at which SOC the capacitor is at the start time of the high frequency PWM input signal?
- I have seen multiple examples of people using RC Low-pass filters for smoothing out a PWM blockform input signal (example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fsb7kxDxYGw). And the smoothing takes effect once the frequency of the PWM signal is high enough (higher than the cutoff point). What is the advantage of using such an RC low pass filter as opposed to putting a capacitor in parallel with the load and skipping the resistor in series. Seeing as in this scenario (PWM signal with a single frequency from which we want an analog DC voltage or something close to it) we don't care about certain frequencies being filtered out or not as long as the given input signal is smoothed out.
  Isn't the resistor just introducing extra losses in this scenario or do i misunderstand and is there in fact a good reason to add the resistor in this scenario?

In an article on AllAboutCircuits (https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/low-pass-filter-tutorial-basics-passive-RC-filter/) I read an explanation about the low pass RC filter where it was compared to a voltage divider (where there is 1 fixed impedence, the resistor and 1 frequency dependent impedence (the capacitor). Where at higher frequencies the impedence of the resistor is higher relative to the impedence of the capacitor, hence more of the input voltage will drop over the resistor resulting in an attenuated output signal at higher frequencies. In this setup the loss in amplitude of the output compared to the input will fully be converted into heat via the resistor? (please correct me if im wrong). To what extent can this waste of energy via the resistor be resolved by replacing it by an inductor such as a coil?

Lastly, perhaps there are better ways than a low pass RC or RL filter of smoothing out such a PWM signal for approximately 3A power draw. The output voltage can vary a bit (i would say 1-2volt variation is acceptable in this application (approx 2% relative to max input voltage). Please let me know if i should be looking at a different filter/method altogether in this use-case.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is essentially asking for tuition on RC filters, which is pretty basic electronics. It's a Q&A site, rather than discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service, which is effectively what you're asking for. VTC for those reasons. You'll find plenty of detailed and free documentation on RC filters available on the internet for you to research and learn from.

Answer (score 1):

No, the R in the filter is not just a current limiter. In an ideal circuit you have no need for current limiting. The R is just what makes it an RC filter when combined with C. Even with arbitary values like giga-amps and megavolts, the R is needed to set the time constant with C for the RC filter. If R is zero then you have no filter as time constant is zero.

Yes, you can replace the R in a RC filter for an L, but then it stops being a first order RC filter and becomes a second order LC filter.

The capacitor does not need to be charged before turning PWM on to RC filter. Of course you can do so if you want.

If you skip the R and just put C over a load, you don't have a RC filter any more. Applying PWM directly to a capacitor would just charge and discharge the capacitor infinitely fast with infinitely high current (assuming ideal circuit).

And the exact reason why LC is used for switch mode power supplies instead of RC is the power loss is less.

Yes, doing RC filter for 3A power draw sounds like you should be looking at different filter than RC. You generally don't need an RC filter if you already have a buck converter. Preferably use a constant current LED driver in place of buck regulator.

And if the PWM frequency is high, and you are driving LEDs, what difference a RC filter makes if you can't see the high PWM frequency.

Comment: could you please elaborate on "And if the PWM frequency is high, and you are driving LEDs, what difference a RC filter makes if you can't see the high PWM frequency." ? Thank you

Comment: In which way? How fast PWM you have and can you see it? If you don't see it then no filter needed.

Comment: The reason i thought a filter would be needed regardless of pwm frequency is because the LED is rated for 36v and without filtering/smoothing the output signal would be a blockform with 82v (input voltage) peaks which I think will damage the LED. But perhaps they wont if you keep the duty cycle low enough..